# Shuffle multiple files in same order

Tags: java, linux, bash, random, shuffle

**Setup:**

I have 50 files, each with 25000 lines.

**To-do:**

I need to shuffle all of them "in the same order". 
E.g.:

If before shuffle:

```
File 1  File 2  File 3
A       A       A
B       B       B
C       C       C
```

then after shuffle I should get:

```
File 1  File 2  File 3
B       B       B
C       C       C
A       A       A
```

i.e. corresponding rows in files should be shuffled in same order.

Also, the shuffle should be deterministic, i.e. if I give File A as input, it should always produce same shuffled output.

I can write a Java program to do it, probably a script to. Something like, shuffle number between 1 and 25000 and store that in a file, say shuffle_order. Then simply process one file at a time and order existing rows according to shuffle_order. But is there a better/quick way to do this?

Please let me know if more info needed.

Comment: The big issue you have (but may have not noticed yet) is how you will put ONE file into a predetermined order ... particularly if you cannot assume that the entire file can be held in memory at one time.  You may need to create "intermediate" files (with each line having the intended order prefixed to the line) and then go through those in a ping/pong mode until you finally have a file in order.

Comment: Adjust your question if you do have to handle "file won't fit in memory" and I can give you suggestions about a "merge sort" process.

Answer (score 1):

The next uses only basic bash commands. The principe is:

- generate a random order (numbers)
- order all files in this order

the code

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$#" in
    0) echo "Usage: $0 files....." ; exit 1;;
esac

ORDER="./.rand.$$"
trap "rm -f $ORDER;exit" 1 2
count=$(grep -c '^' "$1")

let odcount=$(($count * 4))
paste -d" " <(od -A n -N $odcount -t u4 /dev/urandom | grep -o '[0-9]*') <(seq -w $count) |\
    sort -k1n | cut -d " " -f2 > $ORDER

#if your system has the "shuf" command you can replace the above 3 lines with a simple
#seq -w $count | shuf > $ORDER

for file in "$@"
do
    paste -d' ' $ORDER $file | sort -k1n | cut -d' ' -f2-  > "$file.rand"
done

echo "the order is in the file $ORDER"  # remove this line
#rm -f $ORDER                           # and uncomment this
                                        # if dont need preserve the order

paste -d "  " *.rand   #remove this line - it is only for showing test result
```

from the input files:

```
A  B  C
--------
a1 a2 a3
b1 b2 b3
c1 c2 c3
d1 d2 d3
e1 e2 e3
f1 f2 f3
g1 g2 g3
h1 h2 h3
i1 i2 i3
j1 j2 j3
```

will make `A.rand B.rand C.rand` with the next example content

```
g1 g2 g3
e1 e2 e3
b1 b2 b3
c1 c2 c3
f1 f2 f3
j1 j2 j3
d1 d2 d3
h1 h2 h3
i1 i2 i3
a1 a2 a3
```

real testing - genereting 50 files with 25k lines

```
line="Consequatur qui et qui. Mollitia expedita aut excepturi modi. Enim nihil et laboriosam sit a tenetur."
for n in $(seq -w 50)
do
    seq -f "$line %g" 25000 >file.$n
done
```

running the script

```
bash sorter.sh file.??
```

result on my notebook

```
real     1m13.404s
user     0m56.127s
sys      0m5.143s
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably very inefficient but try below:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( $(for i in {1..25000}; do
    echo "$i"
done | shuf) )


for file in files*; do
    index=0
    new=$(while read line; do
        echo "${arr[$index]} $line"
        (( index++ ))
    done < "$file" | sort -h | sed 's/^[0-9]\+ //')
    echo "$new" > "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to shuffle them with a `python` script. By setting the same seed for every shuffling, you will obtain the same final data order.

```
import argparse
import logging
import os
import random

from tqdm import tqdm


logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)


def main(args):

    assert os.path.isfile(args.input_file), (
        f"filename {args.input_file} does not exist"
    )

    logging.info("Reading input file...")
    with open(args.input_file) as fi:
        data = fi.readlines()

    logging.info("Generating indexes")
    indexes = list(range(len(data)))

    logging.info("Shuffling...")
    random.seed(args.seed)
    random.shuffle(indexes)

    logging.info(f"Writing results, in place? {args.in_place}")

    if not args.in_place:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(args.input_file)
        new_filename = name + "_shuffled" + ext
        args.input_file = new_filename

    with open(args.input_file, "w") as fo:
        for index in tqdm(indexes, desc="Writing to output file..."):
            fo.write(data[index])
        fo.flush()
        os.fsync(fo)

    logging.info("Done!")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Shuffle file by lines.")

    parser.add_argument('--input_file', type=str, required=True, help="Input file to be shuffled")
    parser.add_argument('--in_place', action="store_true", help="Whether to shuffle file in-place.")
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, required=True, help="Seed with which the file will be shuffled.")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

You can run this script with:

`python shuffle.py --input_file File1 --seed 123`

`python shuffle.py --input_file File1 --seed 123`

`python shuffle.py --input_file File1 --seed 123`

And all the files will be shuffled in the same way.